# VBA: How to declare a graph as an object

Tags: excel, vba

In the sheet called `sheet1`, there is a graph named `graph1`.  This graph was named using the Name Box. I want to declare it as an object so that it can later be copy and pasted. I have the following code:

```
Sub dumb()

Dim tot_cap As Object

Set tot_cap = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Object("graph1")

End Sub
```

The code above results in the following error message:

```
run time error 438: object doesn't support this property or method
```

How can you properly declare a named graph object in VBA?

Comment: `Shapes`, or `ChartObjects`.

Comment: @BigBen I changed the declaration to ```ChartObjects``` and now I'm getting ```Run time error 13: Type mismatch```. Any chance you could write a formal answer so I can see exactly what you are talking about?

Comment: Record a macro where you select the chart

Comment: Did you do `Dim tot_cap As ChartObject` and then `Set tot_cap = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").ChartObjects("graph1")`?

Comment: @BigBen thank you, I realized the mistake was I wrote ```Dim tot_cap As ChartObjects``` instead of ```Dim tot_cap As ChartObject```.  Do you know if the ```ChartObject``` variable type is sufficient for pasting into PowerPoint presentations?

Comment: Should be fine, yes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[BigBen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67437741/1188513) is correct, but leaves you with the exact same underlying issue.

Error 438 can only be thrown on late-bound code. Here, the late binding is accidental.

`ThisWorkbook.Sheets` yields a `Sheets` object, which is a collection of various types of sheet objects. So far, so good. Problem is, `Sheets.Item` (implicitly invoked *default member*) is yielding an `Object`, because there are various types of sheet objects, and `.Item` would inevitably blow up if it tried to return a `Worksheet` object every time.

But you *know* that `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")` is a `Worksheet` object. So you can tell the compiler you know, by extracting a local variable - even better, dereference it off the `Worksheets` collection, for clarity:

```
Dim sheet As Worksheet
Set sheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheets1")
```

Now when you make a member call against that `sheet` object variable, you'll get compiler assistance, and when you type that `.` dot operator you'll see that a `Worksheet` has no `Object` property - and you'll quickly find its `ChartObjects` property in the inline autocompletion dropdown list, and now writing member calls doesn't feel like magical incantations anymore.

[Rubberduck](https://rubberduckvba) has code inspections that can locate implicit late binding for you, and if `Sheet1` exists at compile-time in `ThisWorkbook` it will also [recommend to leverage the sheet's *code name*](https://rubberduckvba.com/Inspections/Details/SheetAccessedUsingString) (and it can automatically make this change for you).

Answer (score 4):

An embedded chart is a [`ChartObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.chartobject).

```
Dim tot_cap As ChartObject
Set tot_cap = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").ChartObjects("graph1")
```